# Discord bot mention mobile / pc

Tags: discord.js

I'm getting strange behavior from discord, not sure how to solve it. My bot mentions someone, but sometimes the mention goes like @invaliduser on mobiles or is displayed like  @numberid on pc. After a while, it shows the mention right or stops showing it properly. Any ideas why this happen?
This problem starts a few days ago.

This embed message triggered by the event guildMemberAdd.

```
newUser = member.id;
const bemvindoEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setColor('FADF2E')
                .setTitle('Welcome')
                .setThumbnail(`${avatar}`)
                .setDescription(`<@${newUser}>`);
```

Comment: Can you shos your code, how do you send the mentions? Edit the code into the question

Comment: As mentioned, the code worked fine until a few days ago. I noticed that in another server too. Not my bot tho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the answers were helpful, they didn't solve my problem.
It seems that the issue was with Discord's Cache, so I used the following code `const newUser = await client.users.fetch(member);` before mentioning the user. So far it has worked.

Answer (score 2):

On v13 you can use [(Member|User).toString()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=toString) to parse  a member or user object into a sendable string mention.

```js
// Use the member itself, not the id
newUser = member;
...
.setDescription(newUser.toString());
```

Attempting to parse a mention in a raw fashion will lead to unpredictable results, best to let the library do the work for you.

Comment: *"Attempting to parse a mention in a raw fashion will lead to unpredictable results"* - the source code itself shows `.toString()` is `<@${this.id}>`, so you just gotta use the ID